# MySQL - Query failing validation

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT `user_id` FROM task_schedule WHERE `',DAYNAME(NOW()),'` = TRUE')
INTO @task;
PREPARE statement FROM @task;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

It is used to query this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `task_schedule` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `program_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sunday` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monday` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tuesday` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wednesday` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thursday` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friday` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `saturday` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query works as expected. I have Used MySQL Workbench tool, JetBrains Datagrip, also in command line it works.
But, every single online mysql syntax checker fails the query, with the following  error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'PREPARE stmt FROM @query EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt'
> at line 3

That is a problem for me, since I use third party company tool, which will use this query against our DB, and they also report the same error. Apparently they use similar or same syntax checker.

What is wrong with this query?

**More INFO:**

It seems nothing is wrong with he query. Somerthing is wrong with the Validators.

This query:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
 SET @a = 3;
 SET @b = 4;
 EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;

 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Works everywhere, except in validators and in my case. This is taken from [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Looks like validators are not supporting PREPARED Statements.

Comment: *I have this query:* This is 4 separate queries (more precisely - statements). Either enable multi-query in your client settings (if possible) or put these statements into stored procedure.

Comment: Can't use procedure, dont have access there. But still, mystery remains. Why the validators fail it? I have update the original question with more information.

Comment: Nobody can consult you about unspecified online validation tool issue. Except its support team if exists.

Comment: These ones for example:
- https://en.rakko.tools/tools/36/

- https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/
 and others. Same behavior. They do not validate even the official example, which is now in my question.

Comment: First have no any documentation. Second needs authorization.

Comment: I am not sure why the eversql one requires authorization, but in any case, any validator you might use will probably fail.

Comment: Add CREATE PROCEDURE and BEGIN-END to your code - and you'll receive "This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet".

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line : DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
It cancels the query before it's run!

Edit: This works with the example Mysql database (sakila)

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM actor WHERE actor_id = 1')
INTO @task;
PREPARE statement FROM @task;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

Comment: That statement is there for a reason. Also, even without it, it is still the same problem.

Comment: Ok I tried it now with the last line included. It works again. I think the problem is with your select query.

Comment: For example, this validator (one of many), https://en.rakko.tools/tools/36/
It will VALIDATE 'INTO' statement.
But it will fail validation to everything after that line.

Comment: Why do you care if it works on your server and doesn't work on online validators? Who knows what they do?

Comment: Thats is valid statement. I use third party tool, in which I save the query, and then it is run. But before that tool allows me to save it, they do validation, which fails and it wont let me save it :)

Comment: I see. And you have to use that third party tool?